# Typing Text value in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a textbox with datepicker as

```
<input type="text" id="date" placeholder="Enter a Date: " value="19-APR-2014" />

$('#date').datepicker({
            'dateFormat': 'dd-mm-yy',
        'onSelect' : function(text, values){
                 /*Handle Select*/
    }
});
```

It does not allow me to edit the Month name in the textbox.

Comment: The date value is invalid, you've set the dateFormat to allow `19-04-2014`, not `19-APR-2014`

Comment: What would be the correct format to allow 19-APR-2014 00:00:00

Comment: The default date format in jquery date picker is :- mm/dd/yyyy and not the one you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Per the guide on this page: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ 
you want to use `dd-MM-yy` if you want the date to be 19-Apr-2014

```
<input type="text" id="date" placeholder="Enter a Date: " value="19-APR-2014" />

$('#date').datepicker({
            'dateFormat': 'dd-MM-yy',
        'onSelect' : function(text, values){
                 /*Handle Select*/
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NwGk/